# Is it posible to pass a variable by reference on an object creation in php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using laravel excel to upload data from an excel file to my database. The syntax is like this:

```
Excel::import(new CompanyImport(company_id, $errors), $request->file('import_file'));
Excel::import(new OfficeImport(office_id, $errors), $request->file('import_file'));
Excel::import(new ClientImport(client_id, $errors), $request->file('import_file'));
```

What I want to do is save all errors (generated inside every Import class) inside the $errors array.

I tried using the & syntax but I get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&', expecting ')'

This is CompanyImport:

```
class CompaniaImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithMultipleSheets
{
    public function  __construct($company_id, &$errors)
    {
        $this->company_id = $company_id;
        $this->errors = $errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about exceptions or custom error messages?

Comment: Please show the actual code you are trying to execute. It is not clear what actually you are doing.

Comment: The error is just a plain array that contains the date, description, and the line where it occurred

Comment: This will depend if the function you're calling expects a reference or not.

Comment: Where are you adding the `&`?

Comment: You mean this: new CompanyImport(company_id, $errors)?

Comment: new CompanyImport(company_id, &$errors)

Comment: The `&` needs to be added to the function definition, not where you call it. So it would be on `CompanyImport`'s __construct function.

Comment: if you dont understand @aynber solution, add the code of the class `CompanyImport` to your question.

Comment: I edited my class definition but still doesnt work